# Find $\phi, \psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, each nilpotent of order 2, whose composition is idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$\phi: V \rightarrow V$ is nilpotent of order 2 if $\phi \phi$ is the zero endomorphism. Now composition of two such endomorphisms need not be nilpotent of order 2. Find $\phi, \psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, each nilpotent of order 2, whose composition is idempotent.

Correct me if I've misunderstood but I'm reading that they are both nilpotent of order 2 (which I'm told means the function multiplied by itself comes out to $0$) so then $\phi\phi$ must equal $0$ and $\psi\psi$ must equal $0$? And then they are idempotent (which means $\rho\rho = \rho$)?

So would $\phi$ and $\psi$ both just be $0$ to be able to satisfy $\phi\phi = 0$, $\psi\psi = 0$?

Comment: $\phi^2=0$ does not imply that $\phi=0$, for example consider $\phi(x,y)=(y,0)$.

Comment: lWhy not let $\phi=\psi =0$

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth  I expect the OP  wants a case in which $\phi \psi$ is not nilpotent, though the two factors are.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for the factors to be nilpotent of order 2, which implies by definition that they can't be 0: $\phi$ is nilpotent of order $n$ means $\phi^n=0$, but $\phi^{n-1}\neq0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:  $$\phi(x,y)=(y,0) \;\;\&\;\;\psi(x,y)=(0,x)$$

Then, with $\rho=\phi\psi$ we have  $$\rho(x,y)=\phi\psi(x,y)=(x,0)$$  and $\rho^2=\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

Since linear maps can be represented by matrices.  We need to find 2x2 matrices which are nilpotent.  Square matrices which have  1s along a (left/right) diagonal other than the main diagonal, and 0s everywhere else are nilpotent.  So,
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is now easily checked that
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I was still typing my answer when lulu's came it.  My answer is a matrix form of lulu's. Well slightly different example, but the same idea.